# How to test screen rotation in Android Emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, rotation

If I open a browser in emulator and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>F9</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, the screen rotates but browser doesn't. 
[image]

To test I downloaded a native app and installed it on my emulator and phone both. The app catches the rotation of phone but on emulator similar thing happened.

I googled it and read few posts on Stackoverflow, I found that its a bug in Emulator of particular version.

- But which version of emulator runs it fine?
- I simply downloaded the `adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702` and I have `eclipse(juno)` with it. Eclipse has `Andoird SDK Manager` inside it, which helped me to chose the latest APIs, SDK tools etc. I downloaded those, what did I miss that doesn't support rotation.[image]
- I also read that if I if uncheck `Hardware keyboard Present` then it would work but it didn't.
- I also tried by uncheck `Host GPU`, no luck.
- Finally I was told that need to specify in `AndroidManifest.xml` that I want to support both `landscape`and `portrait` both. But I have not created any `android project` in eclipse I simply created a device and now checking its rotation with its own browser and by installing a `apk` file from internet.

  **Are there any concrete steps/tested way that work out screen rotation on android emulator?**

Comment: have the emulator configured for **Auto Rotation**?

Comment: @yashhy, how to do that?

Comment: press 9 or 7 right numerics in keyboard..

Comment: @MSGadag, I already mentioned that I tried it, but its not working. Its rotates emulator not app. See screenshot.

Comment: Try to use my solution. That may solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But which version of emulator runs it fine?

4.3 (API Level 18) and below.

> Are there any concrete steps/tested way that work out screen rotation on android emulator?

Download an emulator image for Android 4.3 (API Level 18) or below, create an emulator from it, and use that. You will find emulator images in your SDK Manager:

[image: Android SDK Manager]

In the above screenshot, you will see API Level 17 and 18 emulator images towards the bottom of the picture.

Comment: let me try this , btw where I can get the image for `Android 4.3 (API Level 18)`?

Comment: @paul: In your SDK Manager.

Comment: Superb it worked, smooth. But why APIs above 4.3 not supporting?

Comment: @paul: There's just a bug in the emulator. Hopefully, someday, they will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by changing one setting as given below:

1. Open Menu
2. Goto Settings
3. Goto Accessibility
4. Check the check box for "Auto-rotate screen".

This may solve your issue.

Comment: it was already checked, before I decided that I will ask this question on SOF.